# Are jQuery objects actual DOM objects? Is it correct to add properties to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095336/is-it-bad-practice-to-add-properties-to-dom-nodes) I found out [here](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) that there are downsides in extending DOM objects.
Is it OK to do something like the following?

```
var tr = $('<tr>');
tr.myCustomProperty = 'Some string value';
```

I know that there is a `.data()` method on jQuery, but the above seems easier to work with. I also wonder if my `tr` variable is holding an actual tr DOM Element or any other kind of object.

Comment: No, they are jquery objects. the moment you re-select the tr or use a method that generates a new jquery object, the property is lost.

Comment: No, essentially $('<tr>') is a function whose name is "$" and parameter is '<tr>'. It's not a DOM object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery handles DOM objects in special array called [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). You can think of it as array of DOM elements which is extended to have all the jQuery methods.

You can access the DOM element in your example like this:

```
tr[0]
```

but all the reasons not to store data that way still apply.

As @Kevin B mentioned, it's not ok to do what you're trying to do (extending jQuery object)  because you'll lose the custom properties on every reinitialization.

Answer (score 3):

Kevin is incorrect. You can store something in the TR in most browsers by doing the following:

```
var tr = $('tr').eq(0); // get a single TR from the DOM
var actualElement = tr[0]; // get the actual element object from the jQuery object
actualElement.myCustomProperty = 'Some string value';
```

Comment: Kevin's statement is correct. Diego added the property to the jQuery object. That is - as Kevin wrote - a bad idea.