# How can I derive a specific subtype of HTMLElement from its tag name and store that element on another one?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I have a function that creates a node and return such node. For example:

```js
addElement: function ({
    parentNode,
    elementName,
    tagName,
  }) {
    // Creates and appends the new node.
    parentNode[elementName] = document.createElement(tagName);
    parentNode.appendChild(parentNode[elementName]);

    return parentNode[elementName];
  }
```

Specifically, `parentNode` is another element, `elementName` is a string (e.g., `container`) and `tagName` is the type of element to create, also a string (e.g., `div`).

My issue is that I don't know exactly what will be the type returned. The return type is going to be an extension of `Element` but it could be `HTMLDivElement` as well as `HTMLAreaElement`. I have the same problem with `parentNode` as well.

How do I fix this in TypeScript?

Comment: Why returning `Element` is not good enough?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425282/how-can-i-derive-a-specific-subtype-of-htmlelement-from-its-tag-name-and-store-t/75426938#comment133086393_75425282) @carlosV2 See [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) in the handbook for an answer, along with explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple questions being asked — I'll start with the primary one which seems to be:

### How can I derive a specific subtype of `HTMLElement` from its tag name?

In your example function, you use this invocation to create an element that is later returned:

```ts
document.createElement(tagName)
```

By examining the TypeScript DOM library source, we can see that the function signature of [`document.createElement`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.9.5/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L4594-L4601) is:

```ts
/**
 * Creates an instance of the element for the specified tag.
 * @param tagName The name of an element.
 */
createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(tagName: K, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K];
/** @deprecated */
createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementDeprecatedTagNameMap>(tagName: K, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElementDeprecatedTagNameMap[K];
createElement(tagName: string, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElement;
```

- In the first [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) signature, the return type is a specific subtype of `HTMLElement` when the `tagName` matches a key in the `HTMLElementTagNameMap` interface.
- The second signature deals with deprecated elements, so I'll ignore it in this answer.
- The final signature returns a generic `HTMLElement`. This is the result when the tag name is not recognized.

Using [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), a type utility can be written to derive a specific type of element from the tag name map (if it exists), or `HTMLElement` in the generic case (if the tag name is not recognized):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsC2AbAooi8IDtgDEBOA9vACoCGA5gHKkYA8ZVN0EAHsFgCYDOUXweAS0zkAfFAC8AKChQG1DFFbtM3KAGsIIAgDNYxALIAZVOizA5TfaTDSZUAPx6jJjNgsYrYANruIAXVsZAC4nYzRXYABuSUlQSFkARglYBBRws3wiX1oAIg4BADcckWi7AHoygD17GLjoYgAmZLgkFwzCEgp5CFzSYtKZCura8HqAZmbUtuxMzsY6HPgQAFoAYwBXPiJliHTsfsChmqA)

```ts
type HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName extends string> =
  TagName extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap
    ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[TagName]
    : HTMLElement;

type T1 = HtmlElementFromTagName<"div">;
   //^? type T1 = HTMLDivElement

type T2 = HtmlElementFromTagName<"a">;
   //^? type T2 = HTMLAnchorElement

type T3 = HtmlElementFromTagName<"my-custom-element">;
   //^? type T3 = HTMLElement
```

This can be used for the return type of your function:

> Note that in the function below, I omit the side effect statements from the code in your question — I'll address that in the next part.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsC2AbAooi8IDtgDEBOA9vACoCGA5gHKkYA8ZVN0EAHsFgCYDOUXweAS0zkAfFAC8AKChQG1DFFbtM3KAGsIIAgDNYxALIAZVOizA5TfaTDSZUAPx6jJjNgsYrYANruIAXVsZAC4nYzRXYABuSUltAFdMAGNgAQJMKES8CFJ2FzMoegp5ZjZOHj5BYREACmAiphDfAEoQuCQ87HwiX0LGDDEAb1tEtL5FcPzxKA4CRLiIgDpM7NyJ7Fr6jCaoUh42lDXcQhJNiF7ikWiZLOA4vHSIQ+iAXxiRzDHH+ABGCQysnIQDrAaoAIg4AgAbqCmlc7AB6eEAPXsb1GwHG8AATH9loDgWDSDC4TJESi0R8MV8AMy4gGrUzrUHwEAAWjmfCIrMejOAxMCUDJqKAA)

```ts
function createElement <TagName extends string>(tagName: TagName): HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName> {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName) as HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName>;
  return element;
}

const elm1 = createElement("div");
    //^? const elm1: HTMLDivElement

const elm2 = createElement("a");
    //^? const elm2: HTMLAnchorElement

const elm3 = createElement("my-custom-element");
    //^? const elm3: HTMLElement
```

---

### How can I associate arbitrary data with a DOM node?

There are many reasons not to mutate objects that you don't own (e.g. extending them by adding properties), but I won't discuss that here — you can read other answers like [Is it bad practice to add properties to DOM nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095336/438273) or [Why is extending the DOM/built-in object prototypes a bad idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/104320/31737), and do additional research to understand further.

JavaScript offers you the [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) to associate arbitrary data with DOM nodes, and I'll use one to answer the rest of your question. But first...

In your example code, you use the [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method to insert the child element into a parent node. The `appendChild` method is on the `Node` interface ([TS DOM library source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.9.5/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L10090)), so the type of `parentNode` should be or extend `Node`.

In the question, you mentioned that `elementName` will be a `string`, so that means that your function's parameter should be typed like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsC2AbAooi8IDtgDEBOA9vACoCGA5gHKkYA8ZVN0EAHsFgCYDOUXweAS0zkAfFAC8AKChQG1DFFbtM3KAGsIIAgDNYxALIAZVOizA5TfaTDSoAfj1GTGbBYxWwAbTcQAurYAuR2M0F2AAbklJUEgoAEEODmczAAVCMC56CnlmNk4ePkFhMXEoAG9bCFCzHKDCoXJImTBSPBqCDgggyg6IJqhgbKYgn0iAX0jJAGMCTD4oUkTk7AkoLMYFJXzefgaRAApbMsVq7ByAGigWtrPey8GN6DGghKTT4DSCDPWckUkASiCcCQy1whBIQzoPhKYgqMhmc2AJ1MK1KHAIUwArmEAHRTNqkdig-YPHL-BY8YEod74Ig+H5MESTZqtdqdHHWSAqADCAAsBIgOPsqijgP9mVAAPSSqAASQA5IhEFAZgoAEakKZqAYEAb8rgBWzSq6s26dTwisI5XyrS1mCVtYCYvCYZFhcaTTpTRCslWzebXNldKA9TqTBHzKrwVaLN6i-bHO1nYZQABECMGQggeFTl0DZog90hwdTHAEADdU1AxuLbDJpQA9OySIA)

```ts
type AddElementProps<TagName extends string> = {
  elementName: string;
  parentNode: Node;
  tagName: TagName;
};
```

It is used with a function that looks like this:

```ts
const addElement = <TagName extends string>(
  { elementName, parentNode, tagName }: AddElementProps<TagName>
): HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName> => {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName) as HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName>;

  parentNode.appendChild(element);

  // I'll come back to this:
  // parentNode[elementName] = element;

  return element;
};
```

and using it returns a type like this:

```ts
declare const parentNode: Node;

const elm = addElement({ elementName: "container", parentNode, tagName: "div" });
    //^? const elm: HTMLDivElement
```

So far, so good — but what about the commented line?

If the line is un-commented, this compiler error occurs:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsC2AbAooi8IDtgDEBOA9vACoCGA5gHKkYA8ZVN0EAHsFgCYDOUXweAS0zkAfFAC8AKChQG1DFFbtM3KAGsIIAgDNYxALIAZVOizA5TfaTDSoAfj1GTGbBYxWwAbTcQAurYAuR2M0F2AAbklJUEgoAEEODmczAAVCMC56CnlmNk4ePkFhMXEoAG9bCFCzHKDCoXJImTBSPBqCDgggyg6IJqhgbKYgn0iAX0jJAGMCTD4oUkTk7AkoLMYFJXzefgaRAApbMsVq7ByAGigWtrPey8GN6DGghKTT4DSCDPWckUkASiCcCQy1whBIQzoPhKYgqMhmc2AJ1MK1KHAIUwArmEAHRTNqkdig-YPHL-BY8YEod74Ig+H5MESTZqtdqdHHWSAqADCAAsBIgOPsqijgP9mVdWbdOp4RWEcr5VnKzOEoAB6ABUUGQeEIeFsAD8jcaTaazUbbKCoAJ4GBEAIpgJgIgQFBeaQeKRMFAAORekA+gbgaAAIwgU1ImK4uTAbS4XAEsygOiDsR99WEgYjmB9SLDUCjEA4AwI1pUrFT0B9PU6Ppxth6Zc6LF4AnImEJmLaUAA7k7eQtJXgmOw8MndDEqxnyIGex6oNoCJiVMnvZPfTWIHX9gB2AAMAFYAMzkjVqqIyNrALve5XYcaTdfEACMq03nmnvlVmu1uoI+pkQCgOAqAzUkYhgw3XpA3dHhMFLeBCSmflhCbCsE3bTtu0XMd13TXZMxxfYACZjx3U9zyAA)

```ts
const addElement = <TagName extends string>(
  { elementName, parentNode, tagName }: AddElementProps<TagName>
): HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName> => {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName) as HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName>;

  parentNode.appendChild(element);

  parentNode[elementName] = element; /* Error
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Node'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Node'.(7053) */

  return element;
};
```

TypeScript is telling us that it is not valid to access or set a value at arbitrary string properties on `Node`s:

```ts
type T1 = Node[string]; /* Error
               ~~~~~~
Type 'Node' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.(2537) */
```

and this is where the [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) comes in. Instead of storing the element at a property on the parent node itself, you can store all of the data in an associated `WeakMap` (and retrieve from it later):

> In addition to the linked MDN docs, you can learn more about weak maps at the question [What are the actual uses of ES6 WeakMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29413222/438273)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsC2AbAooi8IDtgDEBOA9vACoCGA5gHKkYA8ZVN0EAHsFgCYDOUXweAS0zkAfFAC8AKChQG1DFFbtM3KAGsIIAgDNYxALIAZVOizA5TfaTDSoAfj1GTGbBYxWwAbTcQAurYAuR2M0F2AAbklJUEgoAAVSPDNKAg4IABFSYFIJeMTgAVJEWgAlCABjAjwOWj5BYQAaYOczERFIyUrMPihMVIgPXMwIAHcoAHUIUjUPWhS0poSk7HmMrNIRAAoASg6untIODhbXAlXczds+tKDVhtsIUOSmILqhcnuZR9NsIJgDEI-YD3bZBABuBAEHAkYgA3rYAPQIqAAcQgwCgwAAFtAOOsoAQAEYAKwqGO0hHgmJxUBGUzUUHg1igmwEugEGKKSUOIEULAEfC420RyKqUHK3PYUBywzGBGGLLZUA5UA4BAgXEwAHJgKDbPsMdc1tkhv0PAA6cjozZG7b2BywgC+HRkSKgAEluhA8BjsdAiaTyhihMACNToHTpozmUJxaQuNAVRwodqMawBRjCRBtFUIAErmbrOaE8Abf0mkbMtldlFXciAMro8NQMFFACu-t0fvUmmVmGbAbJmLD3e+YWpWVp8agxLbPQlU3YHHzMkr608Y+eGF8uU32EizqiBqgVuAJ1wlPO4hZBZuUDuDyeKxevH47xBfwB56gAB8oG2VGzIQIGhcQ4VsJJgDbPB+yNC1TzLNJtjsc0NyfYB5D8A8OhiaAAEEjnPOJCDALh6AoTC+WUVQ3mEMRr3hL50Mw1432ESIZDARJkn6W5+g4zEKJfHxsKPeUDkI9DcnIxgFCUTgeFo0RLhkWFFGYpgmi45YMPLQTZOgR0ggI450OIghSJkzCREkUFYAQFB0PwIgfCsph6PAmRjz3DFrzVco2zCc0FyyCBz02bIDLtac4CQc9nJIIS6B8dpaygbSeLSc1rEgFQAGEsQERAOE2HyaxFKAACFs1zFcoDdDKVn6NCgUwndrx8l16uRPDtHYPA6sOUygWIM5+k2RrdIWdTWs0mawnKmRIOg-tOskQ8gA)

The type of your element map looks like this:

```ts
type ParentNodeData = Partial<Record<string, HTMLElement>>;
/* Equivalent to:
type ParentNodeData = {
  [x: string]: HTMLElement | undefined;
}
*/
```

and creating the weak map of the corresponding type looks like this:

```ts
const nodeMap = new WeakMap<Node, ParentNodeData>();
```

Adding an element to such a weak map involves a few steps, so creating a helper function will be useful:

```ts
const addElementToNode = (
  node: Node,
  elementName: string,
  element: HTMLElement,
): void => {
  // Get the data object from the weak map (if it already exists)
  // or create a new one (if it doesn't):
  const nodeData = nodeMap.get(node) ?? {};

  // Insert the object into the weak map in case it didn't exist before:
  nodeMap.set(node, nodeData);

  // Set the value of the key in the object to the element that was just created:
  nodeData[elementName] = element;
};
```

Finally, your function can be updated to use the helper function like this:

```ts
const addElement = <TagName extends string>(
  { elementName, parentNode, tagName }: AddElementProps<TagName>
): HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName> => {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName) as HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName>;

  parentNode.appendChild(element);

  // Before:
  // parentNode[elementName] = element;

  // After:
  addElementToNode(parentNode, elementName, element);

  return element;
};
```

You will undoubtedly need to retrieve data from the weak map later, so here's another helper function for that task:

```ts
const getElementFromNode = (
  node: Node,
  elementName: string,
): HTMLElement | undefined => {
  return nodeMap.get(node)?.[elementName];
};
```

---

We've reached the end — here's all of the final code together in a single playground:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsC2AbAooi8IDtgDEBOA9vACoCGA5gHKkYA8ZVN0EAHsFgCYDOUXweAS0zkAfFAC8AKChQG1DFFbtM3KAGsIIAgDNYxALIAZVOizA5TfaTDSoAfj1GTGbBYxWwAbTcQAurYAuR2M0F2AAbklJUEgoAAVSPDNKAg4IABFSYFIJeMTgAVJEWgAlCABjAjwOWj5BYQAaYOczERFIyUrMPihMVIgPXMwIAHcoAHUIUjUPWhS0poSk7HmMrNIRAAoASg6untIODhbXAlXczds+tKDVhtsIUOSmILqhcnuZR9NsIJgDEI-YD3bZBABuBAEHAkYgA3rZ9sBev1Mtkhv0PAA6cgQYCba4Qbb2BywgC+kRkBKxXFx+P6TQJqNIuyuKPWnm+YXkflynLMkXJUURUBxwBOuEI8HO4igl0p-Vu9IeTxWL14-HeIL+APFUAAPlAAK4qCDaIQQaHiOG2JLAQ14TDItJY0V0tLbOyYjkq4Dc3wCjoxaAAQSO4rihDAXHoFG5ijYnB4b2EYhl8K+Pu5rw1wgpUDAiWSCqgqzz2UYGCCPgDQoI3SRh2OPtyMYrzATKiTOdEcqgsMUmaYTQLy199Kg5bjpKCoabQIjBCjre5IkkoNgCBQPvwRB8y6YqetMmFfOwuQ4BHKhrCmPKSSyEHFm0nTCJpB4cCQ4p3JFjTH3GDtLYI5FmkmLWJAKgAMIABYCIgHCbKewAsjIjbisQZz9JsIErOOyHck0yGoVAtr2o6yE1kAA)

```ts
type HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName extends string> =
  TagName extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap
  ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[TagName]
  : HTMLElement;

type ParentNodeData = Partial<Record<string, HTMLElement>>;

const nodeMap = new WeakMap<Node, ParentNodeData>();

const addElementToNode = (
  node: Node,
  elementName: string,
  element: HTMLElement,
): void => {
  const nodeData = nodeMap.get(node) ?? {};
  nodeMap.set(node, nodeData);
  nodeData[elementName] = element;
};

const getElementFromNode = (
  node: Node,
  elementName: string,
): HTMLElement | undefined => {
  return nodeMap.get(node)?.[elementName];
};

type AddElementProps<TagName extends string> = {
  elementName: string;
  parentNode: Node;
  tagName: TagName;
};

const addElement = <TagName extends string>(
  { elementName, parentNode, tagName }: AddElementProps<TagName>
): HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName> => {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName) as HtmlElementFromTagName<TagName>;
  parentNode.appendChild(element);
  addElementToNode(parentNode, elementName, element);
  return element;
};
```